# Use of html5 in web app

Tags: ipad, html, web-applications

I have a web app which has standard things for learning based app like student reg, teacher reg, assignments, lessons, content, reports, etc

This uses Java in the middle tier.

We are planning to redesign this app which would mainly mean changes in presentation layer. Now we plan to havr the same html work on both desktop and iPad, through adaptive css...i am completely aware of the css stuff..media queries and all.

My question is should i use html5 for the new pages..i have not used it much..but wanted to know what benefits does it offer apart from the standard audio, video support and the obvious things.

I have a lot of AJAX calls in my app. Will html5 help in any way for that?

I wanted to know some good reasons for using html5, given the same page is going to render with slight differences on desktop vs iPad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [To HTML 5 or not to HTML 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864732/to-html-5-or-not-to-html-5)

Comment: It is not duplicate, bcoz iwant to know about mobile browser compatibility as well...

Comment: You're already using HTML5, whether you want to or not. Some browsers are treating your markup as HTML5 even if you try to tell it otherwise.

Comment: Please read and understand my complete question before answering...

Comment: @testndtv - You say "My question is should i use html5 for the new pages." I say, "You have no choice." The answers to the question deceze points to make it clear that the remainder of your question is too broad to be sensibly answered here. You should ask more specific questions about the individual aspects of HTML5

Comment: -1 for question being overly broad and ignoring the appropriate information that other users provided.

Comment: Sorry if u do not understand the question..not my fault..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 will allow you to use the semantic HTML5 tags, and if you care about validating your HTML to a W3C Standard, HTML5 allows things that XHTML/HTML4 didn't - such as a using  anchors as block-level elements.

There is plenty of material on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

Ajax is javascript and has nothing to do with HTML(5) beyond access to things like the canvas element. You can choose to use, or not use, any of the newer elements of HTML5 and continue doing whatever you're doing in every category and not notice the difference. So I don't know what you mean by "using HTML5". You use the new elements or you don't. There isn't really anything to "switch" to.